# creating columns from a single column

Tags: python, multiple-columns, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with multiple columns, I have an address column within the dataset that i want to clean and divide into multiple columns. The address column contains the following:

EAGLE'S EYE SPORTS CLUB 5021 TOWNS ROAD, QUEENS 40560621 TS/A D

I want to break the column above and create the following columns as part of the dataframe from the above column using python:

Name: EAGLE'S EYE SPORTS CLUB
Address: 5021 TOWNS ROAD
Borough: QUEENS
ID: 40560621
Tag: TS/A
Place: D

Comment: Does the address field contain newlines between the rows, or just spaces? If the former, simply split on newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you put commas within the initial column, otherwise the principle of splitting is unknown.
Then, the code should be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
a='EAGLES EYE SPORTS CLUB, 5021 TOWNS ROAD, QUEENS, 40560621, TS/A, D'
b=a.split(',')
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Address', 'Borough', 'ID', 'Tag', 'Place'])
df.loc[len(df)]=b
print(df)
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks Sergii, this solution didnt work out.